# Why am I getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<style>
.addedclass {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<!-- All the HTML markup first -->
<p id="bordertext">Red Text</p>


<!-- All of the js code at the last -->
<script>
    let elem = document.getElementById("bordertext");
    elem.classList.add("addedclass");
</script>
```

Why am I getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"? I know that's because it can't find the item, but why can it not?

Comment: Because it's not a function. Check spelling. Look up docs. Auto complete in the console or IDE

Comment: Check out the answers and comments in the duplicate question and also you have a typo: It's `getElementsByClassName()` not `getElementByClassName()`

Comment: That's because you are calling the element even before it is rendered to the DOM. Just put all of the js code below HTML and it will work fine. I will update the demo.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the "s" in elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss "s". 
document.getElementsByClassName(); 
refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp